# How to use Next.js generateMetada with client components and translation?

Tags: next.js, next-intl

```
"next-intl": "^2.19.1",
"next": "13.4.13",
```

Inside my dynamic page:

```
import slugify from "@/utils/Slugify";
import { youtubeVideos } from "@/utils/YoutubeDB";
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

type Props = {
  params: {
    slug: string;
    locale: string;
  };
};

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: Props) {
  const youtubeVideo = youtubeVideos.find(
    (video) => slugify(video.title) === params.slug
  );

  return {
    title: `Bla bla | ${youtubeVideo?.title}`,
    description: youtubeVideo?.descriptionShort,
    keywords: youtubeVideo?.keywords
  };
}

export default function Page({ params }: Props) {
  const t = useTranslations("YoutubeDB");

  const youtubeVideo = youtubeVideos.find(
    (video) => slugify(video.title) === params.slug
  );

  return (
    // my component
  );
}
```

Here nextintl for translation `const t = useTranslations("YoutubeDB");` give me an error:

```
- error node_modules\next-intl\dist\src\react-server\index.js (11:10) @ notSupported
- error Error: The React APIs of next-intl are currently not available in Server Components.
```

But when I convert it into client component with `"use client"` this time error disappears but `generateMetaData` does not work. How to make both them work here?

Comment: Really simple: You can't. You will need a different way to fetch translations for the server side as the `generateMetadata` function does exclusively run on the server. Check out [this article](https://blog.stackademic.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-internationalization-with-next-js-13-eb1be3d1a9e2), it might help.